# Taco notation for Kroenecker product

Tags: matrix-multiplication

I'm using the online taco compiler demo (http://tensor-compiler.org/codegen.html) and confused as to the use of letters in the notation.

I'm trying to do the kroenecker product of a 4x4 and 3x3 matrices which would result in a 12*12 matrix.

I don't understand the meaning of the letter. this seemed intuitive to me.

```
A(i,i) = B(j,j) * C(k,k)
Computations with transpositions are not supported, but are planned 
for the future.
```

I don't know if this is the correct message or more likely i've done it wrong. any advice would be greatly appreciated. thanks :-)